# What exactly does initialCapacity of HashMap does?

Tags: java, hashmap

If I specify `HashMap map = new HashMap(1);`
then will it contain `HashMap` with only 1 bucket and all the elements added to the `HashMap` will stay in that bucket no matter how good my hashing algo is?

Comment: To which language/library are you referring?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc? Because it explains it: *An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance: initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created...*

Answer (score 0):

The constructor takes zero, one or two arguments: the `initialCapacity` and the `loadFactor`. If the initial capacity is exceeded, more buckets will be added. The load factor determines when and how many buckets are added.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), especially the following paragraphs:

> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance: initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.
>
> As a general rule, the default load factor (.75) offers a good tradeoff between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the operations of the HashMap class, including get and put). The expected number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into account when setting its initial capacity, so as to minimize the number of rehash operations. If the initial capacity is greater than the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash operations will ever occur.

Answer (score 0):

The size of hashMap is determined using two factors:

1. load factor
2. initial size

Default value of load factor is 0.75 and that of initial size is 16. This means when you are initializing a hashMap using new HashMap(), the size of array of buckets will be 16. Once the size reaches 0.75 of 16 (which is 12),the size of hashmap will be automatically incremented.

If the HashMap is initialized using HashMap(int var1), the load factor is set to its default value (0.75) and initial size will be set to var1.

HashMap can also be initialized using new HashMap(int var1, int var2) in which case the size and load factor will be set by the developer. It is always better to use this type of initialization if you have an idea about the number of key-value pairs you will be inserting to the map. If you do not have an idea, then use new HashMap().

Always ensure that you are overriding hashCode and equals method in the key class, if you are using a user defined class as key. This is because the hashcode of key is used for inserting and retrieving data from a hashmap.